# Unable to find virtualenv or django after installing with pip

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I installed virtualenv using pip and now receive the following error whenever I actually try and use it:

```
% virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2705, in <module>
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 668, in require
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 571, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.11.2
%
```

Similarly, I installed django with pip, and when I try and import django in python I get: `ImportError: No module named django`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install virtualenv again, this time using easy_install instead of pip. easy_install gave me an error saying that it was having issues with my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Lo and behold, after reading http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath, `PYTHONPATH` is what python uses to find modules, and my `PYTHONPATH` was unset.

After setting `PYTHONPATH` to `/lib/python3.3/site-packages` (where pip was installing my modules), both virtualenv and importing django functioned properly.

Note: because I have both python2.7 and python 3.3 installed, for me `pip` actually installs packages to `/lib/python2.7/site-packages` while `pip3` installs packages to the aforementioned `/lib/python3.3/site-packages`.

For the unfamiliar, information on setting environment variables can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables